# Create a restricted area

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to build a restricted area for a website in which only the registered user can see his personal profile and his posts. The staff users can see all users profile and related posts.

This is **models.py**:

```
...
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    authorized_users = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        related_name="user_set",
        default=1,
        )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
...
```

As you can see one post can have more then one author(*authorized_users*).

This is **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@permission_required('user.is_staff', raise_exception=True)
def listUsers(request):
    users_list = User.objects.all()
    context = {"users_list": users_list}
    template = 'usermanager/users_list.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

@permission_required('post.authorized_users=username', raise_exception=True)
def singleUser(request, username):
    user_single = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    context = {"user_single": user_single}
    template = 'usermanager/single_user.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

def listPost(request):
    posts_list = Post.objects.all()
    context = {"posts_list": posts_list}
    template = 'usermanager/list_post.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

def singlePost(request, pk):
    post_single = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    context = {"post_single": post_single}
    template = 'usermanager/single_post.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

If I'm logged in as staff I can see the list of users(*view listUsers*) and the single user with all his posts(*view singleUser*); but if I'm logged in as non staff user I see the message *403 Forbidden*. This isn't what I want to see becouse I want to see only my profile and my posts.

How I can solve this?

Comment: You have `user.is_staff` in the `permission_required` for `singleUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved is using this:

```
def userProfile(request, username):
    if request.user.username == username:
        user_details = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, username=username)
    elif request.user.is_staff:
        user_details = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, username=username)
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
    context = {
        "user_details": user_details,
        }
    template = 'usermanager/reading/user_profile.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

It is possible to use the same strategy for the others views.